# How to move a geometry along a image?

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I draw a `lineString` and add a `"drawend"` event to add image to the end of `lineString`. Now I want to move the image to a position by `translate interaction`, it works,  but the endpoint of `lineString` didn't move along the image.

Does someone know how to make the **last coordinate** of  `linestring` move along with the image coordinate. I want to bind them, then i can move them together. Here is example http://jsfiddle.net/Wenhua1224/kux7fw49/2/

```
document.getElementById('move').onclick = function (){
  map.addInteraction(select);
  map.addInteraction(translate);
  map.removeInteraction(interaction);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by listening to the geometry `change` event being fired.  When that happens, get the coordinates of the image and apply it as the last coordinate of the line geom.  Here's a snippet:

```
// a is the point (image) feature
a.getGeometry().on('change', function() {
    var line = e.feature.getGeometry();
    var coords = line.getCoordinates();
    coords.pop();
    var last = a.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
    coords.push(last);
    line.setCoordinates(coords);
}, this);
```

You could have replaced the whole geometry object, or update the existing geom (like the above example).

At the same time, you can do the opposite as well, i.e. when modifying your line, update the end image as well, as such:

```
// e is the drawend event, which contains the line feature
e.feature.getGeometry().on('change', function() {
  var end = e.feature.getGeometry().getLastCoordinate();
  a.setGeometry(new ol.geom.Point(end));
}, this);
```

Notice that in the above snippet, the geometry was entirely replaced, which works too.

See the [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kux7fw49/7/) in action with the above changes.

Comment: it looks good， but the image didnt rotate following the line direction， do you have idea to solve it？

Comment: If you compare the first and last points of the line, you can calculate the angle, which would result in the rotation.  Then, use this rotation value to set it to the style of your image feature.

Comment: thanks for your continuous help, I want to ask if it possible to snap the starting point and ending point of linestring only and only allow to modify those 2 point.  Because when i snap on the part between starting and ending nodes and clicked there, it will add new node point, then it will not be a straight line, I want a line which only allow modify staring and ending nodes (a straight line with arrow image to point someplace).

Comment: You should start new threads for new questions.  Make sure to search for existing similar questions/responses first.